# How to make windows transparent by default

Tags: 16.04, unity, gnome-terminal, lts, transparency

Is it possible for windows to be transparent by default in Unity 7.4 on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS?  I used the opacity tool in CompizConfig Settings Manager to set up a keyboard shortcut, but is there a way to have windows be transparent by default?

Comment: Related: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/StandardShaderMaterialParameterAlbedoColor.html

Comment: question has been revised, no longer a duplicate

Comment: Do you mean the transparency applied to all window?

Comment: @Liso I want all windows to be slightly seethrough when they're opened - right now they're all completely opaque by default but I can use a keyboard command to change it - I don't want to have to use a keyboard command, I want it to be transparent by default when I first open a window

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**NOTE**: For those who interested on getting transparent window, you might want to install Compiz Settings and its plugins:

```
sudo apt install compizconfig-settings-manager compiz-plugins
```

---

1. Press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd>, type `ccsm` on field to launch Compiz Setting.
2. On Accessibility section, click **Opacity Brightness & Saturation** plugin.
3. On the current tab, expand Window Specific Settings.

[image]

4. Click <kbd>New</kbd> button, then click <kbd>+</kbd> and Edit Match window will be appear.

[image]

5. On Type field, change value from "Window Class" to "Window Type". Then type "Normal" on Value field. Don't forget to click <kbd>Add</kbd> when you're done.

[image]

6. Back to edit window, you have to set your preferred opacity values, you can set the values from 0 to 100. Less values make the window more transparent, we'll use 80 for example.

[image]

7. Click <kbd>Close</kbd> then, as you can see there are new defined specific settings.

[image]

#### Before effect

[image]

#### After effect

[image]

Comment: Good answer ! You might also mention that `ccsm` is not installed by default so user will likely need to run `sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager`

Comment: @Serg nah I have ccsm

Comment: @ChristianF97 Sure, you have, but other users who find this answer via Google might not have it. It's always best to make answers as general as possible

Comment: Does this work on ubuntu 19.04?

Answer (score 3):

Does not work any more on Ubuntu 18.04 and later, because `ccsm` works only on Unity desktop environment, and latest versions switched to GNOME.

As [this site](https://tipsonubuntu.com/2018/11/12/make-app-window-transparent-ubuntu-18-04-18-10/) says, you can enter this line on your terminal:

```sh
xprop -f _NET_WM_WINDOW_OPACITY 32c -set _NET_WM_WINDOW_OPACITY `printf 0x%x $((0xFFFFFFFF * 80 / 100))`
```

Of course you can replace **80** in the command with whatever value you want, in percentage.

Then the cursor will become a cross, and you can click a window to change its opacity.

**NOTE**: You have to run this command for *every* window you have open or you wish to apply that opacity setting to. Once a window is clicked, the cursor becomes back normal.