# Can we have a transparent HUD like image/information layer on display?

Tags: display-manager, transparency, photo, system-info

Sometimes I adore the HUD information or to have a favorite image picture on the front of the display layer (always on top and un-clickable).
[image]

That would look like this and help our operation or just for the family picture to encourage our work.  Can anyone have the idea to make this happen on Linux/Ubuntu in near future?

Comment: Maybe "the other way round" suits your usecase: Put a background image on desktop (i.e. the family picture) then set all windows to transparent. There is an answer on https://askubuntu.com/questions/852780/how-to-make-windows-transparent-by-default how to achieve that.

Comment: Thank you I did that before, the windows aren't useful or readable when the very low opacity. This idea meant to be the merge workspaces, the console on the front layer and desktop on the second layer, we can do it by Alt + Ctrl + F2 but it's kinda useful it's on the HUD and bring it on and off.

Comment: Probably with opaque windows and transparent overlay the legibility will also suffer, though